# NodeJS: Get value outside async function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

```
const _sodium = require('libsodium-wrappers');
(async (model = this._modelUser) => { //Had to pass this._modelUser otherwise it'd be undefined
    await _sodium.ready;
    const sodium = _sodium;

    let password = sodium.crypto_pwhash_str(Utils.urldecode(data.password), 7, 677445);
    model.password = password;
    console.log('In:' + model.password); //Good value
})();

console.log('Out:' + this._modelUser.password); //Undefined
```

So in this case, `this._modelUser.password` is undefined outside function. I'd like to wait for `this._modelUser` to get the right password value before continuing.

Does anyone have an idea about how to fix this ? Thanks for your help

Different than [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) because of the syntax (async => ()) and because of usage of a specific module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/libsodium

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises help in achieving this .

```
const _sodium = require('libsodium-wrappers');
(async (model = this._modelUser) => { d
    await _sodium.ready;
    const sodium = _sodium;

    let password = sodium.crypto_pwhash_str(Utils.urldecode(data.password), 7, 677445);
    model.password = password;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(model.password) resolve(model.password); 
    else reject(model)
   })
})()
.then((a) =>{
//handling code
})
.catch((a) => {
//handling code
})
```

Comment: I tried your method, but instead resolve(model.password) I put resolve(model)

So in then(), I did:
this._modelUser = a;

Otherwise, this._modelUser became null.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

so the purpose of [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) is to be none blocking and returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object that you can use to act on what is returned.

It is difficult to know exactly what you plan to do with your model after assigning your password, but I would recommend you assign your password to your model outside of your current function with something like this:

```js
const _sodium = require('libsodium-wrappers');

const generatePassword = async () => {
    await _sodium.ready;
    const sodium = _sodium;

    // Not sure where you have got data from, could be passed in locally.
    return sodium.crypto_pwhash_str(Utils.urldecode(data.password), 7, 677445);
}

generatePassword()
    .then((password) => {
        this._modelUser.password = password;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log('error: ', error))
```

You can of course split this up even more to be more functional.

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for you help

I tried your code, but I keep falling into the catch.

I added some console.log inside generatePassword, data.password is well defined, and sodium.crypto_pwhash_str send a good hash.

Is there a way to check why it got catched ? Thanks

Comment: Hi Dushy, I see you have gone with the other answer, but yeah the error comes through as a parameter in the catch, I will update the code to reflect this